# Why does every STL container have a swap function defined as a member function?

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the `queue` container in STL.

It is my understanding that `swap()` available in the `<algorithm>` header would work just fine.

I understand that `swap()` will only copy the `queue` instances superficially, that is, only the `front` and `rear` pointers will be copied, along with the `size`, and other data members.

The entries in the two queues would not physically swap places, but I do not see why that would be nescessary in any scenario as once the pointers and size is swapped, the two queues will effectively be swapped.

Comment: Typically - if some STL container has a member function, functionality of which, is also available via `<algorithm>`, it means that STL container, knowing the structure of data, may perform said functionality faster, that the generic `<algortihm>` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before C++11 introduced move semantics, the generic implementation of `std::swap` had no choice but to do two copies. Conceptually, this:

```
template <class T>
void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
  T t(a);
  a = b;
  b = t;
}
```

Notice that this generic `std::swap` doesn't know *anything* about internals of the object passed in (because it can be called with an arbitrary user type, for example), and thus has to do copies. Note that for containers, this means copying the elements.

Providing an optimised member function `swap` which just re-points some internal pointers is therefore a huge performance win.

Since move semantics were introduced, the generic swap can be made more efficient using moves. Again, conceptually:

```
template <class T>
void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
  T t(::std::move(a));
  a = ::std::move(b);
  b = ::std::move(t);
}
```

Of course, in practice, it probably has requirements about the move operations involved being non-throwing, and all sorts of extra bits.

With move semantics in place, the optimised member versions are perhaps less important than they were before. But it's still possible that with knowledge of the exact implementation details of a type, swapping it can be faster than three generic moves.

---

In addition to the discussion above, notice that type-specific overloads of `std::swap` exist for almost all types defined in the standard library. What these overloads do is simply call the optimised `swap` member function on one of the operands. That way, you have the best of both worlds: a generic free function `swap` which can be called with anything, but which has optimised implementations for everything the standard library is aware of.

It would be possible to forego the member functions and provide the optimised implementations inside the `std::swap` overloads directly, but this would mean they'd likely need to be friended and could be perceived as worse accessible to user code.

Comment: Still, the member `swap` can be more efficient than the 3-move `std::swap`.

Comment: @MSalters I was typing exactly that addendum as you commented.

Comment: I suppose the OP was expecting that the free `std::swap` could already have been specialised for each container (and `friend`'d if needs be). Which, to be fair, isn't a _terrible_ idea AFAICT.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe it already is "specialised" (or actually overloaded) like that, caling the member version.

Comment: @Angew: Really? Hmm.. never heard that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  See specialisations: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the standard, the overloads are defined next to each of the container etc. definitions. E.g. C++11 23.3.5.6 [list.special] for `list`.

Comment: Doesn't that suggest that the answer to the OP's question is simply "convenience and not having to make lots of `friend` declarations", then? i.e. the "generic" or base-case swap implementation doesn't actually come into the picture at all. So the first bit of this answer wouldn't apply.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're actually right. I hadn't remembered the overloads when starting to write the answer. I might rephrase it later.

Comment: Okay glad I'm not going mad :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the free `std::swap` has overloads for each container, you're right that member function `swap`s aren't really necessary. The free overloads could have been declared `friend`s and performed all the implementation-specific, container-specific magic to make an efficient swap.

As it is, they invoke the member `swap`s. I suppose this allows for additional flexibility in how to call those functions, and it saves lots of `friend` declaration.

I'm not aware that there's anything more to it than that.

Answer (score 1):

When the [uniform call syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf) (2014 version by Bjarne Stroustrup) is finally adopted, after some final tweaking, your question will become moot in the sense that `std::swap(my_queue, another_queue)` and `my_queue.swap(other_queue)` will likely be aliases of the *the exact same function*. Unfortunately, that won't happen for C++17. Maybe in C++20? One can dream...