# Queue Swap C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I want to implement a some functionality, where I will be needing two queues from STL. And I frequently have to do some operations based on input data,and I may need to move all elements from one queue to another and vice versa.But I am thinking that if i maintain reference to two queues,then I can just swap references instead of two queues.So is it possible in C++ that I have two references to two queues, and i can swap those references as per requirement ?How can i do it if possible?Normally i would have done as follow:

```
Queue<int> Q1;
Queue<int> Q2;
I can swap like:
Queue<int> Q3=Q1;
Q1=Q2;
Q2=Q3;
```

But it will do entire data copy and can be a very time consuming operation.How can i represent Q1 and Q2 as reference and then perform just swap of reference?

Comment: What about `std::swap`?

Comment: _"...and i can swap those references..."_ references can't be rebound; however pointers can.

Comment: @RichardCritten `std::reference_wrapper` can also be used to have a non-null, rebindable reference.

Comment: yes,my bad.References cannot be re bounded.One way is to have my custom queue class and i can have pointer to those queues and then can easily swap two pointer variables.But i was looking if I can somehow have the same thing with stl containers?Will  std:swap internally move data from one queue to another ?

Comment: Yes, `std::swap` will move the containers, so there won't be any copies.

Comment: i mean using std:swap,will it actually move one queue data to another like the in mentioned in snippet in code?Because i am looking to avoid actually data copy and somehow wanted to swap  the references/pointers to queue so that it can be done in constant time.Is it possible using STL queues?I can anyhow do this with custom queues as i mentioned because above

Comment: `std::swap` will do that for you. But you should probably try it before you ask questions?

Comment: Yes, it'll work with custom containers, and do moves efficiently, but you have to write an efficient move for your class.

Comment: with custom implementation of queue,I can represent my to queue as two pointers Queue * Q1 and Queue * Q2 and whenever I need to swap two queues,I can just swap Q1 and Q2 pointers only and get it done.There are no moves as i swapped only two pointers.@Thrasher actually std:swap will do the work if i try but i wanted to be sure that there should be no actual movement of data.The way i can swap two pointers in custom implementation and get it done.I was looking same solution in C++ STL Queue.

Comment: @rahulsharma Well, `std::queue` supports full move semantics so you should be ok.

Comment: For pre-C++11 there is also a [`swap()` member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718327/why-does-every-stl-container-have-a-swap-function-defined-as-a-member-function).

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::swap`. `std::queue` is movable, so you won't copy anything, it is already very efficient. Just to ensure this is the case with your own `Queue`, add assertions:

```
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<Queue<int>> && std::is_move_assignable_v<<Queue<int>>)
```

Comment: can you tell what exactly do you mean when you say std::queue is movable?

Comment: Read about move semantic here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/2795046.